# React and Electron with Draft.js: "Global is not defined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, draftjs

There is a similar question raised here: [Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined at Object../node_modules/fbjs/lib/setImmediate.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58936238/uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined-at-object-node-modules-fbjs-lib)

And there are two answers on that question that both seem confident they can solve it. The problem for me is--no explanation of how to implement the answers is given.

Basically, I have an electron app incorporating React, everything works fine until I try to implement draft.js into the project. I get the following error:

```
app.js:19805 Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined
```

The log points me to a line in the babel/webpack-compiled app.js:

```
module.exports = global.setImmediate;
```

The specific thing that causes it is narrowed down to an import statement:

```
import {Editor, EditorState} from 'draft-js';
```

One of the answers in the linked question above says to add a global object on the window:

```
(window as any).global = window;
```

What I can't figure out is... what does that mean? In my main.js file, where I create the window (it's just the one window for the entire app) trying to do this throws an error seemingly no matter where I try to do it, and I can't seem to find any reference to defining 'global' at all. Where am I meant to define 'global'?

Comment: Check my answer in the link that you provided in your question. Basically, add this in you index.html file (inside the markups):
<script>
  const global = globalThis;
</script>

Answer (score 28):

global got renamed to globalThis in the tc39 proposal
https://github.com/facebook/fbjs/issues/290

**just add this to index.html** that's how i got it fixed

```
<script>
      const global = globalThis;
</script>
```